# Android : Error:Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I don't know why it happen, but when I want to run a project, I get this message error :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: 
java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/app/FragmentContainer.class
```

I tried to `clean / rebuild` project many times, but I got always same error when I run it.

build.gradle:
http://pastebin.com/nnE9bpN7

Do you have any solutions please? I'm really stuck at that.

Thanks

Comment: What is the content of your build.gradle file?

Comment: I have added it : http://pastebin.com/nnE9bpN7

Comment: Did you add manualy any support library in libs folder??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'` is supposed to be `compileSdkVersion 23`. You're adding Google Play services via dependencies.

`libs` folder is not supposed to contain any support libraries such as `support-v4`. These are added again as a maven dependency:

```
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1"
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1"
compile "com.android.support:design:23.1.1"
```

Comment: Perfect, my issue was this line : compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs') I replaced it by  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1', instead of loading jar manually