# Duplicate entry in build.gradle while implementing Google + login

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-plus, build.gradle

I am trying to integrate Google+ signup/login in a legacy (Eclipse) project imported in Android Studio following [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/) tutorial. I am stuck while importing the dependencies in the **build.gradle** files.

The error says:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':Study Story:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/print/PrintHelperKitkat$1.class
```

I am unable to debug the reason for such an error. The inner level build.gradle file has the following code:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern

apply plugin: 'android'

apply plugin: 'com.github.triplet.play'
apply from: 'signingRelease.gradle'
apply plugin: 'signing'



android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15//lower than 14 doesn't support multidex
        targetSdkVersion 21

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true

        // For blurring images
        renderscriptTargetApi 18
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes{
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.publishApkRelease
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }


    }
    play {
        track = 'beta'
        serviceAccountEmail = '436686241693-d4ts7q2davfmim1s20junur0qd9c7075@developer.gserviceaccount.com'
        pk12File = file('keyfile.p12')
    }

    configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        all*.exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}



dependencies {
    compile project(':Viewpage:viewpage-library')
    compile project(':CountryPicker')
    compile project(':numberpicker-library')
    compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.13.0') {
        exclude module: 'bolts-android'
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }

    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'

    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    //compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.11.0'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0'

    // glide is added to load the g+ profile image. Ignore if you want
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.+'
    compile 'com.shamanland:fab:0.0.6'

    //compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.1.+'


    //compile fileTree(include: 'Parse-*.jar', dir: 'libs')
   // compile fileTree(include: ['ParseFacebookUtilsV4-1.9.2.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile fileTree(include: ['jsoup-1.7.3.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    compile fileTree(include: ['ParseFacebookUtilsV4-1.10.3.jar'], dir: 'libs')


    // compile fileTree(include: ['libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['android-support-multidex.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.3'
    //SwipyRefreshLayout
    compile 'com.github.orangegangsters:swipy:1.2.3@aar'

   // compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'

    compile('com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.0') {
        force = true
    }

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

/*

This is not working yet.

 */

task('increaseVersionCode') << {
    println('in increaseVersionCode')
    def manifestFile = file("AndroidManifest.xml")
    def pattern = Pattern.compile("versionCode=\"(\\d+)\"")
    def manifestText = manifestFile.getText()
    def matcher = pattern.matcher(manifestText)
    matcher.find()
    def versionCode = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1))
    println('in increaseVersionCode '  + versionCode)
    def manifestContent = matcher.replaceAll("versionCode=\"" + ++versionCode + "\"")
    manifestFile.write(manifestContent)
}

task('incrementVersionName') << {
    println('in incrementVeriosnName')
    def manifestFile = file("AndroidManifest.xml")
    def patternVersionNumber = Pattern.compile("versionName=\"(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\"")
    def manifestText = manifestFile.getText()
    def matcherVersionNumber = patternVersionNumber.matcher(manifestText)
    matcherVersionNumber.find()
    def majorVersion = Integer.parseInt(matcherVersionNumber.group(1))
    def minorVersion = Integer.parseInt(matcherVersionNumber.group(2))
    def buildVersion = Integer.parseInt(matcherVersionNumber.group(3))
    def mNextVersionName = majorVersion + "." + minorVersion + "." + (buildVersion + 1)
    println('Major Version '  + majorVersion)
    println('Minor Version '  + minorVersion)
    println('Build Version '  + buildVersion)
    def manifestContent = matcherVersionNumber.replaceAll("versionName=\"" + mNextVersionName + "\"")
    manifestFile.write(manifestContent)
}

//Activate this if you wish for Gradle to handle the build number increments.
/*
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    println('When task is added: ' + task.name)
    if (task.name == 'generateDebugBuildConfig') {
       // println('IN IFSTATMENTWITH : ' + task.name)
        task.dependsOn 'increaseVersionCode'
        task.dependsOn 'incrementVersionName'
    }
}*/
```

The project level (outer) build.gradle has the following code:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
     //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
        classpath 'com.github.triplet.gradle:play-publisher:1.1.4'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        //classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.4.0-beta3'
    }

    System.properties['com.android.build.gradle.overrideVersionCheck'] = 'true'

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

The folder structure looks like the below image:

[image]

Please point out the areas which I need to modify to fix the issue.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35156072/android-errorexecution-failed-for-task-transformclasseswithjarmergingfordeb

Comment: That did not work for me, I had tried it already.

Answer (score 0):

First, try to use the same API for `compileSdkVersion`, `buildToolsVersion`, `targetSdkVersion`, `support:appcompat` dependency, `support:design` dependency, `support-recyclerview` dependency, `support:cardview` dependency. In your **app build.gradle**, you need to stick to **API 23**.

Afaik, if you use:

```
useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

you don't need to add this dependencies:

```
compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
```

because it doing the same with `useLibrary` (If my memory serve me well).

Then in your **root build.gradle**, you only need one build gradle tools:

```
//classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0' Use only one.
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
```

And last, try to not **using multidex** for your application. Because an android app is faster without the multidex. Imho, By a glance of your build.gradle, you can go without multidex.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure that your Android SDK is updated and use the same version of libraries that you are specifying as your Project's Dependency. Now to answer this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':Study Story:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/print/PrintHelperKitkat$1.class
```

com.android.support:support-v4 and support-annotations package is imported multiple times with different version so you need to exclude them as below:

These are importing support-v4, support-annotations 23.0.0:

```
compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    }

compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.0') {
            exclude module: 'support-v4'    
            exclude module: 'support-annotations'
        }

compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.0') {
                exclude module: 'support-v4' 
                exclude module: 'support-annotations'          
            }
```

This is importing support-v4, support-annotations 22.0.0.

```
// Just don't import this library as it's already imported in 'com.android.support:design'
    compile('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0') {
                        exclude module: 'support-v4' 
                        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
                    }
```

This is importing support-v4 25.0.1. You should never specify dependencies having + in dependency: 'com.android.support:design:22.+' as that will always force your Project to use the latest libraries while building gradle that might lead to several build errors, some deprecated classes in your Project leaving it unstable. It is always recommended to update SDK on timely basis and specify the dependency version accordingly and verify that the code written is your Project is not missing any class in the latest library. In fact, design library is importing support-v4, appcompat-v7, support-annotations, recyclerview-v7 so you should avoid importing these libraries separately.

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
```

It is again importing support-v4, support-annotations 22.2.1.

```
// Just don't import this library as it's already imported in 'com.android.support:design'
    compile('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1') {
                                exclude module: 'support-v4'
                                exclude module: 'support-annotations'           
                            }
```

This library is importing below modules having version 23.1.1:

```
    compile('com.github.orangegangsters:swipy:1.2.3@aar') {
                                    exclude module: 'support-v4'
                                    exclude module: 'appcompat-v7' 
                                    exclude module: 'support-annotations'          
                                }
```

It is importing support-annotations: 22.0.0

```
compile('com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.3') {
                                        exclude module: 'support-annotations'          
                                    }
```